# JQuery select a inside p Flat Admin V.2

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to register a click event from an a element inside a p element using standard methods. The HTML is from the [Flat Admin V.2](https://github.com/tui2tone/flat-admin-bootstrap-templates/blob/master/html/ui-kits/other.html).

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="../../img/thumbnails/picjumbo.com_IMG_4566.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 id="thumbnail-label">Thumbnail label<a class="anchorjs-link" href="#thumbnail-label"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default SELECT_ME" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: the other half of the question, which is Javascript.

```
$(document).on('change', 'a', function(e) {
    console.log('does not register event')
})

$(document).on('change', 'div.caption > a', function(e) {
    console.log('does not register either');
})

$('.SELECT_ME').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('this doesn\'t work either');
});

$('.SELECT_ME').change('click', function(e) {
    console.log('nope, this doesn\'t work either');
});
```

Comment: Might be a css issue. I've had buttons not be clickable before because of z-index issues. Something to check anyway.

Comment: You're missing half the code needed to properly respond to your question.

Comment: what other half do you need @SamAxe?

Comment: the javascript you are trying to register the click event with.

Comment: The question is that standard JQuery is not working. Would you like for me to post fail code?

Comment: `change` event apply for input elements, not on `A` tags

Comment: that last one is a bit of mess isn't it? there's that haste

Comment: Where is this javascript placed? Is it in a $(document).ready() or at the end of the file?

Comment: end of file as an import

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure that your elements are loaded first. You can use $(document).ready() for that. You can use a jquery selector to get the link that you want and then add the click handler to the jquery object.

In the example below, I'm adding a click handler to all links and alerting the link's label when it is clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function () {
          alert($(this).html());
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p><a href="#">This is a test</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">This the second link</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @cjaube. Elements were loaded, and there was an issue for this function and others where the `a` element was nested, specifically inside a `p` element. Your solution above did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it will be useful to anyone in the future, I assigned an `id` to a parent div and drilled in the click event.

```
   <div id="parent_div_id" class="card-body col-xs-12" hidden>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card-body">
             <div class="row no-margin" id="dynamic_insert">

              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I got my parameters the following way, may or may not work for you as intended

```
$('#parent_div_id').click(function(e) {
    var el = $(e.toElement);
    if (el.is('a')) // match
});
```